# Unable to set contract metadata from another contract

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

I am trying to set a contract's metadata and getting some errors.

I have two contracts to work with. One is a factory contract that is instantiated by an account and the other one is a custom contract that is instantiated by the factory. This instantiation happens on an execute message in the factory contract.

In factory contract, the sender account is the admin and on custom contract the factory contract is the admin.

I can set the contract metadata on factory without any problems using arch3 since the sender account is the admin.

But when I want to set the custom contract's metadata after instantiation I get an error saying "**metadata can only be created by the contract admin**".

I have this reply entry point to catch successful custom contract instantiation:

```
#[cfg_attr(not(feature = ""library""), entry_point)]
pub fn reply(deps: DepsMut<ArchwayQuery>, env: Env, msg: Reply) -> ArchwayResult<ContractError> {

let config = CONFIG.load(deps.storage)?;

if msg.id != INSTANTIATE_REPLY_ID {
    return Err(ContractError::InstantiateError {});
};

let reply = parse_reply_instantiate_data(msg);

match reply {

Ok(res) => {
    let msgs: Vec<WasmMsg> = vec![
                // Executing the custom contract for metadata update
        WasmMsg::Execute {
            contract_addr: res.contract_address.clone(),
            msg: to_binary(&CustomContract::UpdateRewardMetadata {
                owner_address: Some(env.contract.address.to_string()),
                rewards_address: Some(env.contract.address.to_string()),
            })?,
            funds: vec![],
        },
    ];

    Ok(Response::new().add_messages(msgs))
}
Err(err) => Err(ContractError::Std(StdError::GenericErr {
    msg: err.to_string()
})),

}
}
```

The execute message and implementation for the metadata update is like this in my custom contract:

```
UpdateRewardMetadata {
    owner_address: Option<String>,
    rewards_address: Option<String>,
},

fn execute_update_reward_metadata(
    _deps: DepsMut<ArchwayQuery>,
    _env: Env,
    _info: MessageInfo,
    owner_address: Option<String>,
    rewards_address: Option<String>,
) -> ArchwayResult<ContractError> {  
        
        // Sender is the factory contract
        // Admin is also the factory contract
    let msg = ArchwayMsg::UpdateContractMetadata {
        owner_address,
        rewards_address,
    };

    Ok(Response::new().add_message(msg)
}
```

I am calling this execute message using my factory contract so I expect it to update the metadata since factory contract is the admin of custom contract.

So the chain of execution is: Sender -> Factory -> Custom

I assume because factory contract is the admin of custom contract it would work but no luck.

Any ideas why it is giving me an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not possible for a contract to update another contract's metadata but the following [PR](https://github.com/archway-network/archway-bindings/pull/11) which is linked to the following [issue](https://github.com/archway-network/archway-bindings/issues/10) now allow's for this. You will therefore need to update to the latest archway-bindings to enable this feature.

The following [code snippet](https://github.com/archway-network/archway-bindings/blob/main/contracts/increment/src/contract.rs#L86-L98) should help:

```rust
    pub fn update_rewards_address(
        env: Env,
        rewards_address: Option<Addr>,
    ) -> ArchwayResult<ContractError> {
        let rewards_address = rewards_address.unwrap_or(env.contract.address);
        let msg = ArchwayMsg::update_rewards_address(rewards_address);
    
        let res = Response::new()
            .add_message(msg)
            .add_attribute("method", "update_rewards_address");
    
        Ok(res)
    }
```